# Calculating a 7 day average

Tags: mysql, sql, count, average, moving-average

I have this query.

```
CREATE TABLE ip_logs (
  `ip_address` VARCHAR(11),
  `start_date` VARCHAR(11),
  `end_date` VARCHAR(11),
  `time_stamp`, VARCHAR(20),
  `mappings`, INTEGER,
  `loc_id` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO ip_logs
  (`ip_address`,`start_date`,`end_date`,`time_stamp`,`mappings`, `loc_id`)
VALUES
 ('120.2.53.21','2020-01-03','2020-01-09','2020-01-03 14:33','2', '5'),
 ('198.3.222.2','2020-01-03','2020-01-14','2020-01-03 7:53', '7','4'),
 ('108.4.213.3','2020-01-04','2020-01-07','2020-01-04 12:13','3', '4'),
 ('128.5.173.4','2020-01-07','2020-02-15','2020-01-07 8:29', '12','3'),
 ('110.6.432.5','2020-01-07','2020-03-01','2020-01-07 11:45','4', '2'),
 ('198.7.222.6','2020-01-10','2020-01-14', '2020-01-10 17:32','8', '1'),
 ('118.8.113.7','2020-01-10','2020-01-19','2020-01-10 20:52','10', '4'),
 ('106.1.212.9','2020-02-24','2020-03-30','2020-02-24 10:08','5', '1');
```

I want to generate the 7 day average of the mappings column. For example, I want to calculate  the average mappings for each day (from  2020-01-03 - 2020-01-10).

Results:

```
 time_stamp | avg_mapping
 2020-01-03 | 4.5 (2 + 7) /2
 2020-01-04 | 3
 2020-01-07 | 8 (12 +4)/2
 2020-01-10 | 9
```

Then return avg(avg_mapping)

Comment: Please show us the result that you want for this sample data.

Comment: @GMB I just updated it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how your question relates to a rolling average. From your data and results, it seems like you just want aggregation and `avg()`:

```
select date(time_stamp) as time_stamp_day, avg(mapping) as avg_mapping
from ip_logs
group by date(time_stamp)
```

If you want the average of column `avg_mapping` in the resultset (which is not the same thing as an overall average of `mapping`), then you can add another level of aggregation:

```
select avg(avg_mapping) as avg_avg_mapping
from (
    select avg(mapping) as avg_mapping
    from ip_logs
    group by date(time_stamp)
) l
```

Comment: thanks... apologies for not framing the question well. Guess I had a misguided understanding of what running average is.

Comment: @user3078335: no problem. Your question was not bad, in my opinion. You provided sample data as `create table` and `insert` statements, which is a best practice for SQL questions. You were just missing the desired results. Next time, you shoud also show your attempt at solving the problem yourself (even if the query is erroring or producint wrong results).